# RDS DNS is not accessible even though it has public accessibility enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have two RDS instances that are configured similarly:

- *Public accessibility* is set to *Yes*

[image]

In both cases my laptop is whitelisted in the respective security groups to connect to the postgresql server on its assigned port.

But only one of the two is visible publicly. In particular

```
nslookup <rds1.dns.name>
```

works.    But

```
nslookup <rds2.dns.name>
```

comes back with

```
 ** server can't find keys.cjiyd6.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com: NXDOMAIN
```

The `vpc` looks like this: note that `dns` is enabled.

[image]

*Subnet* info for one of the three regions (in Mumbai):

[image]

It has been over an hour since the `rds` instance was updated for public accessibility Yes. Why is it still not accessible?

Comment: check security group which you used for RDS

Comment: @aviboy2006  I should have mentioned _In both cases my laptop is whitelisted to connect to the postgresql server on its assigned port._ . The question has been updated.

Comment: Is your RDS in a public subnet? Also what do you mean by accessible? How are you trying to access it?

Comment: @Marcin   The first rds instance is accessible via  `nslookup`  and the second is not. I have added vpc and subnet info above

Comment: The VPC settings you posted don't make public subnets. A public subnet is one with route tables to internet gateway.

Comment: where would I look for that within aws vpc screens? The working rds instance has a similarly configured vpc

Comment: if its inside VPC it will not be accessible outside VPC without VPN

Comment: I modeled the second RDS instance after the first: both have similar vpc configurations. I am wondering if the rds server does actually have an externally accessible IP but there were an issue just with the DNS.

Comment: The VPC you are using, is the default one, or you made a custom VPC?

Comment: If the RDS instance is set publicly accessible, as is the case here, it would have a public IP address, and it _should_ have a public dns name and you'd get some answer to nslookup. It would then be separate issue whether you can actually reach the DB (ie traffic is both allowed and routable). We must be missing some information here, because it looks to me like this should work.

Comment: I suspect this is a bug in AWS: I had initially not noticed and it was set to public accessibility No. I updated to Yes. I will create a new instance using same settings and try out that theory